# Coldbox cannot route encoded url string

Tags: coldfusion, apache2, railo, coldbox

Why is it ColdBox cannot route a url like this:

```
report/http%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com
```

I have Apache in front of Tomcat. If I try to access a url like

```
www.myapp.com/report/http%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.it
```

I get an error from the Apache server :

> The requested URL `/index.cfm//report/http://www.google.com` was not
>   found on this server.

Comment: It sounds like this should be filed under "Apache" and not "ColdBox" as it looks like the request never even reaches ColdFusion.

Comment: So how can I set apache to route url like this?

Comment: The solution seems pretty simple. Adding this: AllowEncodedSlashes On on virtual host solves the problem...